# Picture Source not Changing Image

Tags: html

I have created a "picture" element. With in this I have different "source" tags that have images according to 'media' attribute size and file type.

When I change the screen width the images do not change according to the screen size.

Below is my code

```html
<picture class="c-hero_picture">
    <source media="(min-width: 1200px)" type="image/webp" srcset="./img/webp/canada-1600x730.webp 1x, ./img/webp/canada-1920x730.webp 1.2x">
    <source media="(min-width: 1200px)" type="image/jpf" srcset="./img/jpf/canada-1920x730.jpf 1x, ./img/jpf/canada-1920x730.jpf 1.2x">
    <source media="(min-width: 1200px)" type="image/png" srcset="./img/png/canada-1920x730.png 1x, ./img/png/canada-1920x730.png 1.2x">

    <source media="(min-width: 600px)" type="image/webp" srcset="./img/webp/canada-800x730.webp 1x, ./img/webp/canada-1200x730.webp 1.5x, ./img/webp/canada-1600x730.webp 2x">
    <source media="(min-width: 600px)" type="image/jpf" srcset="./img/jpf/canada-800x730.jpf 1x, ./img/jpf/canada-1200x730.jpf 1.5x, ./img/jpf/canada-1600x730.jpf 2x">
    <source media="(min-width: 600px)" type="image/png" srcset="./img/png/canada-800x730.png 1x, ./img/png/canada-1200x730.png 1.5x, ./img/png/canada-1600x730.png 2x">


    <source type="image/webp" srcset="./img/webp/canada-400x730.webp 1x, ./img/webp/canada-600x730.webp 1.5x, ./img/webp/canada-800x730.webp 2x">
    <source type="image/jpf" srcset="./img/jpf/canada-400x730.jpf 1x, ./img/jpf/canada-600x730.jpf 1.5x, ./img/jpf/canada-800x730.jpf 2x">
    <source type="image/png" srcset="./img/png/canada-400x730.png 1x, ./img/png/canada-600x730.png 1.5x, ./img/png/canada-800x730.png 2x">
    <img class="c-hero_img" alt="…" src="./img/png/canada-400x730.png">
</picture>
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe the best way to solve this is with a css stylesheet

First, create your html.

`<img id="picture" src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/11/29/05/55/adult-1867665__180.jpg">`

The source in the img tag is going to be for the image

Then, you're going to need to define the id of the image such as

```
#picture {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

And then have a media rule such as

```
@media screen and (min-width: 600px) {
    #picture {
        content: url(https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/05/05/02/37/sunset-1373171__180.jpg);
  }
}
```

So, your final version should be something like this:

```css
#picture {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 600px) {
  #picture {
    content: url(https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/05/05/02/37/sunset-1373171__180.jpg);
  }
}

@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  #picture {
    content: url(https://images.pexels.com/photos/1830569/pexels-photo-1830569.jpeg);
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>answer</title>
</head>

<body>
  <img id="picture" src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/11/29/05/55/adult-1867665__180.jpg">
</body>

</html>
```